Become relative import when `buf generate` with `google.type.Date` in TypeScript
When I ran buf generate on a file that included google/type/date.proto, a pb file containing a relative path was generated. However, there is no file with the specified path. The language is TypeScript.
// a part of the generated code
import type { BinaryReadOptions, FieldList, JsonReadOptions, JsonValue, PartialMessage, PlainMessage } from "@bufbuild/protobuf";
import { Message, proto3 } from "@bufbuild/protobuf";
import { Date } from "../google/type/date_pb";

I was expecting it to reference the files output to node_modules(There was no files related google.type in node_modules). How can I get rid of the relative paths?
The files used are as follows.
protos/sample/sample.proto is:
syntax = "proto3";

package sample;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/type/date.proto";

message Sample {
  google.type.Date start_date = 1;
}
service SampleService {
  rpc Initialize(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Sample);
}

buf.yaml is:
version: v2
modules:
  - path: protos
lint:
  use:
    - DEFAULT
breaking:
  use:
    - FILE
deps:
  - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis:f0e53af8f2fc4556b94f482688b57223

buf.gen.yaml is:
version: v2
managed:
  enabled: true
  disable:
    - module: buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
plugins:
  - remote: buf.build/connectrpc/es:v1.4.0
    opt:
      - target=ts
      - import_extension=none
    out: src/gen
  - remote: buf.build/bufbuild/es
    opt:
      - target=ts
      - import_extension=none
    out: src/gen

File structure and commands:
$ tree
.
├── protos
│   └── sample
│       └── sample.proto
├── buf.gen.yaml
└── buf.yaml

$ buf dep update
$ buf generate


I'm running into the same issue - for dependencies, Buf generates a relative path under the assumption that the dependent code is in the same top-level object. buf.gen.yaml allows configuring "inputs" (so in your case something like inputs: ["google/type"]), but that will just result in all the imported files being copied into the project, instead of referencing external dependencies.
Based on https://github.com/bufbuild/protobuf-es/issues/967#issuecomment-2407568290, I suspect there is no way around it.
Did you end up finding a solution?

No, it hasn't been resolved. I gave up on this problem for now.
I removed deps from buf.yaml and temporarily retrieved date.proto when I run "buf generate".

The only work-around I've found is to add a couple "manual" (as in, not handled by buf) steps to the build process:
buf export buf.build/googleapis/googleapis --output ./tmp
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:gen/js -I ./tmp google/type/latlng.proto

